# HTML form, taking unchecked input

Tags: php, html, forms, post, checkbox

Hi I have a form like that

```
<form method=post action="control.php">
<input name="cat[]" type="checkbox" value="blabla" checked>blabla
<input name="cat[]" type="checkbox" value="bleble" checked>bleble
.
.
.
<input name="send" type="submit" id="send" value="send">
</form>
```

in control.php, I want to get unchecked box when I use $_POST[cat]. How can I do that? thanks for help...

Comment: you could only get the checked ones.

Comment: Semantically speaking, if there's some major significance to leaving a box unchecked, then I would examine your user experience to see if a radio button isn't a more accessible mechanism. That way, indicating "no" still has a tangible effect.

Comment: This can be done with AJAX. You can create an array from "input" objects and find the ones that are not checked, then serialize the data and pass it to the PHP. Here is a partial example: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/QrjKA/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkbox groups (`cat[]`) can easily be generated from an array, using a foreach.

```
$cat=array(
  'blabla' => 'blabla',
  'bleble' => 'bleble',
  ...
);

<? foreach ($cat as $k=>$v) : ?>
  <input name="cat[]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$k?>" checked /><?=$v?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

If you have an array with all the possible checkboxes, it is very easy to compare it with the POSTed array of selected checkboxes, and find out which ones are missing.

You can use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) for that:

```
$unchecked=array_diff(array_keys($cat), $_POST['cat']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the unchecked box, you can only get the checked ones.

If you need the unchecked boxes, you'll have to look at the checked boxes and figure out which ones were not checked.